# Apache2 webserver not accessible from outside LAN

Tags: apache2, webserver, openssh

I've just installed Apache2 web server on Ubuntu 22.04 with PHP, MariaDB and Wordpress. I've been following this YouTube guide:

https://youtu.be/pOESHd1G-HI

My Ubuntu machine's ip is: 192.168.1.16. I have set a port forwarding rule on my router however my website (Wordpress) is not accessible from outside my LAN. My external IP is: 109.78.70.248

During the setup I had an issue allowing OpenSSH on my firewall with the command:

`sudo ufw allow OpenSSH`    (time stamp 13:42 on the video guide).

Terminal didn't recognise the OpenSSH command for me.

I'd appreciate any advice, thanks!

Comment: Does your ISP allow traffic over those ports? Many North American and European ISPs block port 22, 80, and 443 by default to prevent people from hosting websites from their home. Alternatively, if you're in an apartment complex and using cable internet, then your IP address is being shared by everyone in the building, so the central modem that splits the signal for the building will block certain ports as well. You'll need to investigate how the network is designed to resolve your issue 

Comment: What, specifically, does "Terminal didn't recognise the OpenSSH command for me" mean? What did you type in, and what errors did it return? Details are crucial - please don't summarize problems, give the details.

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a profile matching 'OpenSSH'

This is the error returned when I enter the command

Comment: I was able to resolve the OpenSSH issue by following the instructions in the below video:

https://youtu.be/2xn5MbRB21o

Thank you for your replies